# Getting error while using my custom embedding layer in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I've made my custom embedding layer but when I'm testing it I'm getting error.
Below is my custom embedding layer.

```
class EndTokenLayer(Layer):

  def __init__(self, embedding_dim=128, **kwargs):
    super(EndTokenLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.end_token_embedding = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.random.uniform(shape=(embedding_dim,)), trainable=True)

  def call(self, inputs):
    end_token = tf.tile(tf.reshape(self.end_token_embedding, shape=(1, 1, self.end_token_embedding.shape[0])), [tf.shape(inputs)[0],1,1])
    return tf.keras.layers.concatenate([inputs, end_token], axis=1)
```

But when I'm testing to my train_dataset(from tensorflow slices) which is having shape of one batch 
x = (16,13,128) and y = (16,14)

```
temp = EndTokenLayer()
print(temp(inputs = train.take(1)))
```

Error logs:
ValueError: Attempt to convert a value () with an unsupported type () to a Tensor.

Answer (score 0):

`train.take(1)` will give you a new dataset with a single element, not the first element of the dataset. Maybe you want something like this:

```py
temp = EndTokenLayer()
for elem in train.take(1):
    print(temp(inputs=elem))
```

Or just:

```py
temp = EndTokenLayer()
print(temp(inputs=next(iter(train))))
```